Como hacer una redirección 301 desde .htaccess
Quiero hacer una redirección desde el archivo .htaccess con el código siguiente:
redirect 301 /clicks.asp?url=http://www.aldomininode.com https://www.miweb.com/
El caso es que lo que quiero es hacer una redireccion desde un archivo con extensión .asp . Es un código que tenía hace mucho tiempo y lo tenía por una serie de enlaces que necesitaba saber cuanto clicks hacían en cada uno.
Con el código incluido anteriormente el navegador me devuelve el resultado:
https://www.miweb.com/?url=http://www.aldomininode.com
Bien yo lo que quiero que al hacer click en el enlace https://www.miweb.com/clicks.asp?url=http://www.aldomininode.com me devuelva el navegador la url del dominio principal esta es https://www.miweb.com/
Yo no sé si hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo?

Toquetear los parámetros pasados a una URL mediante .htaccess es un poco complicado. Yo voto porque los pases por un script en PHP y de ahí leas esos parámetros y decidas donde debe ir usando la función header() de PHP.  Así tendrás más control sobre ellos y podras hasta contarlos de algun modo que se te ocurra en PHP.

aamm... php o asp?  Ahora estoy confundido... pues has puesto la etiqueta PHP pero en tu descripción hablas de ASP, del cual no tengo ni idea, lo siento, pero supongo que tiene funciones similares.

Si es php en .htacces se pueden redireccionar archivos aunque estos no sean con extensión .php

masterguru agradezco tu idea pero no sé como hacerlo. Lo que si te puedo decir que si quito el código de redireccion 301 ya me devuelve la página de error 404. Si no encuentro solucion creo que lo voy a dejar así que devuelva un error 404

Es relativamente facil. Por un lado usa reglas de Rewrite en lugar de redirect y redirecciona todo lo que llegue a /clicks.asp a un script en php, por ejemplo clicks.php.  Luego, dentro de ese script, en PHP, te lees sus parametros con $_GET['url'], y según lo que pongan los mandas a un sitio u otro mediante cabeceras header(), las cuales puedes ser 301 también.  Si buscas ejemplos de cada cosa que he dicho te lo puedes sacar.

Si claro que puedes, y me imagino que esto forma parte de un proceso de migración, a mi me toco hacerlo.
El .htaccess debe contener lo siguiente (Ojo segun tu ejemplo):
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=http://www\.aldomininode\.com$
RewriteRule ^clicks\.asp$ https://www.miweb.com/? [R=301,L]


